# Using a tuple as function arguments

Tags: python

For this function I can use tuple elements as arguments:

```
light_blue = .6, .8, .9
gradient.add_color_rgb(0, *light_blue)
```

What if i have to add another argument after the tuple?

```
light_blue = .6, .8, .9
alpha = .5
gradient.add_color_rgba(0, *light_blue, alpha)
```

does not work. What does work is

```
gradient.add_color_rgba(0, *list(light_blue)+[alpha])
```

which does not really look better than

```
gradient.add_color_rgba(0, light_blue[0], light_blue[1], light_blue[2], alpha)
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could call it like `gradient.add_color_rgba(0, *light_blue, alpha=alpha)` if you know parameter name for the alpha.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the expression slightly by making a tuple instead of a `list` containing `light_blue` and `alpha` e.g.

```
gradient.add_color_rgba(0, *(light_blue + (alpha,)))
```

Comment: Depending on light_blue type is quite nasty. IMO it's better to assume that it's any iterable.

Comment: Ok now i remember this is the way to create a one-element tuple.